# Implement React code in Angular feasibility questions

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have an app written in React which I'm considering moving to Angular. However when I started designing the same functionality in Angular I got stuck as I thought it got too messy, but maybe I’m missing something since I don’t know that much about Angular. Can you describe if what I’m trying to achieve is easy and can be done in a tidy way in Angular?

I have asynchronously loaded combo boxes, where depending on the state show/hide different buttons.

The combo box options usually depend on inputs from one or more other asynchronously loaded combo boxes and other forms of data.

[asyncronously loaded combo boxes and dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuF0Y.png)

On the page, asynchronously loaded combo boxes also provide what views are available to the user, and the views themselves have input options.

[Overall view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmvsS.png)

Basically there are a lot of interconnected components.

Then when every input is gathered from subviews and other combo boxes it’s sent to a server and results come back asynchronously.

Is there a neat and tidy way of doing the above in Angular?

Comment: This question is too broad. You should get to know Angular, try it yourself and then ask specific questions. Why do you want to migrate to Angular anyway ?

Comment: ^^ Totally.  If you don't know anything about Angular, then why are you trying to migrate your app to it?  If it is just so you an learn Angular, then go for it.  You'll learn alot, even if the result is sub-optimal for Angular.